# BeautifulSoup chokes on paths with back slashes

Tags: python, path, beautifulsoup

I wrote a script to automate the process of creating an image gallery. I used `os.path.join()` for creating paths to new image directories.

I only relized after creating all the galleries that using `os.path.join()` was not such a good idea as it creates paths with `\` (on windows) which causes problems with firefox (it doesn't seem to understand the path format and cant find the images).

Id rather not have to create all the galleries again since the gallery headers have to be entered manually. I thought `BeautifulSoups prettify()`  would fix the paths but it chokes on the backslashes.
e.g.

*input:*

```
<td><a rel="group" href="images\042.jpg"><img class="gimage" src="images\thumbnails\thumb_042.jpg" alt=""></a></td>
```

*output:*

```
<td>
 <a rel="example_group" href="images">
  <img class="gimage" src="images   humbnails   humb_042.jpg" alt="" />
 </a>
</td>
```

How can I fix the paths?

Comment: Beautifulsoup is interpreting the \t occurrences as tabs you'll probably have to escape those somehow.

Comment: Do all the backslashes occur in href and src attributes as shown above?

Comment: @GWW: Have a closer look, its not just the `\t` occurrences.

Comment: @~unbuntu: Ya the rest of the paths occur exactly the same as the snippet in my question, just different image names.

Comment: @volting: Would changing all backslashes to forward slashes constitute a solution? Or must some backslashes be preserved?

Comment: @~unbuntu: I dont think there are any blackslashes that need to be preserved (that I know of) are you thinking of a simple str.replace('\', '/')

Comment: @volting: You bet. Or, just to be different, `awk '{gsub(/\\/,"/"); print}' test.html`

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed the first one, \0 is the null terminating character in a string, that's why the text is cut off there.

Comment: @~unbuntu: Thanks, Im on windows 7 -no `awk` so  Ill just use `str.replace()`, if you put that as an answer then it will get my acceptance and vote since you steered my thought in the right direction. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, per the comments, it appears that the problem can be solved with a
global substitution of `/` for `\`:

```
import fileinput
import sys
for line in fileinput.input(['test.html'], inplace=True, backup='.bak'):
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace('\\','/'))
```